A question about a step in the proof of $\{\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\sin(nx)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis in $L^2_{\mathbb{R}}[0,\pi]$
I have a question about a step in the proof of Theorem 3.56 from Linear Functional Analysis by Bryan Rynne and M.A. Youngson, second edition

It defines a function $f_\delta$, with $\delta>0$,
$$
f_\delta(x)= \begin{cases}0, & \text { if } x \in[0, \delta], \\ f(x), & \text { if } x \in(\delta, \pi]\end{cases}
$$
Then it claims

the function $f_\delta(x) / \sin x$ belongs to $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[0, \pi]$

By using $f_\delta(x) / \sin x=f(x)\cdot \frac1{\sin x}\mathbf1_{(\delta,\pi]}$ I think it wanted to avoid the divergence of $\frac1{\sin x}$ near $0$, but why don't we need to avoid the divergence of $\frac1{\sin x}$ near $\pi$? For example, $f=\mathbf1_{[\frac\pi2,\pi]}$, then $f_\delta(x) / \sin x\notin L^2_{\mathbb{R}}[0,\pi]$ since $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\pi\left|\frac{1}{\sin x}\right|^2 d x=\infty$.

If you're going to go this way, then yeah, you need to mollify out the singularity at $\pi$ too.
